# Как поместить метку выше балуна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Как поместить метку выше балуна? Не могу нажать на метку пока открыт балун
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте установить z-index больший у метки

Comment: А как его задать? Я не могу просмотреть код метки, чтобы стили ему менять

Comment: Поменял z-index - помогло